# Find the true one

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

There’s lots of words here, but only a single true one. Find it.
[image: Find the word]

Text version of the image:

```
AQOROZDARPAXRINCOMAQAPO  
VUREZERISXAMPSFEAXPEFIJ  
ZEDZEXARPQIZOMUXAYRAOQO  
WUDUXEDLIASIOMNIDFRINGE  
SGOXENDIIGDSPRADOXPRODO
```

Hint:

> One thing could be of a little help to you. It’s something like a grizzly bear.
>  How’s it like a grizzly bear? You’ll be the same if you kick it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The word is

> TRUE

Because

> Highlighting the letters with closed regions (as below) spells out TRUE.
>  [image]

Comment: So, would you say the hint has something to do with "buckets" then?

Comment: @gnovice That would make sense.  I was wondering about that.